# TextMate indentation detection

Tags: textmate, indentation

Is there any way to make TextMate automatically detect the indentation when opening a file? For example if my indentation setting is set to tabs and I'm opening a file with soft tabs, I want TextMate to change my indentation setting to soft tabs. My Google Fu isn't good enough to find a bundle for this.

Answer (score 0):

[TabMate](http://konstochvanligasaker.se/tabmate/) might work for you - it uses modelines to tweak your settings on a per file basis.

TextMate does do some of that for you, saving your settings on a per *language* setting. (aka: set soft tabs for a .py file and TM will remember that setting for all .py files